# Issue when site move from ssl domain to new domain without ssl

Tags: ssl

First of, I'm using really simple ssl wp plugin. Thanks for this simple & wonderful plugin. I installed this plugin in my wordpress website https://goo.gl/PAEGMm It’s working good on old website with ssl enabled.

When I moved my website to new domain without ssl, It’s redirecting my new domain to https which is not exist. I’m confused how to correct this error.

can any one help to find possible solution of it.

Thanks

Comment: It's a little unclear which websites you are talking about. You shared one that does have an SSL, so what is the website without an ssl that is being redirected? Also, why can't you just disable the plugin there to stop that behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Disable the SSL plugin. Then check the  htaccess file, removing any rewrites for SSL.

You may also need to use a search/replace plugin (I like "Better Search and Replace") to change all instances of https://www.yourdomain.com to http://www.yourdomain.com .

Be aware that there will be implications of *not* having SSL; most current browsers will show a warning to the visitor on access to the site. The visitor will have to go through extra steps to view your site. And there is some SEO issues; your site will be downgraded by search engines if you don't have SSL.

There are free SSL certs available. In addition, many hosting places will install a free SSL certificate.